# Are the functions $\log(n + 1)$ and $\log(n^2 + 1)$ in $\mathcal{O}(\log n)$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How to determine if the functions $\log(n + 1)$ and $\log(n^2 + 1)$ are $\mathcal{O}(\log n)$?

Are the functions $\log(n + 1)$ and $\log(n^2 + 1)$   $\mathcal{O}(\log n)$?

Comment: Spitting out question from you homework assignment without showing any individual effort or even proper formatting is frowned upon on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Just take c=3 in the definition of  big $\mathcal{O}$.

$\log(n^3)=3 \log(n)$ dominate both..

Answer (score 2):

Just use the fact that if

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = c, $$ then

$$f(n)=O(g(n)).$$

For instance,

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln(n^2+1)}{\ln(n)}=2 \implies \ln(n^2+1)=O(\ln(n)).$$

Answer (score 1):

Also, for any fixed positive reals $a, b, c$,
$\log(an^b+c) = O(\log(n))$

To prove this, note that,
for any fixed positive reals $a, b, c$,
$an^b+c
= an^b(1+c/(an^b)) < 2an^b
$
for $c < a n^b$ or
$n > (c/a)^{1/b}$.

Thus, for such $n$,
$\log(an^b+c) < \log(2a n^b)
< \log(n^{b+1}) = (b+1)\log(n)
$
for $n > 2a$.

So, if $n > \max(2a, (c/a)^{1/b})$,
$\log(an^b+c) < (b+1)\log(n)
$ so
$\log(an^b+c) = O(\log(n))
$.

Answer (score 0):

$\log_a n^k = k\cdot\log_a n$ and by the definition of $\mathcal{O}$ that means that $\log_a n^k = \mathcal{O}(\log_a n)$.